# GmailApp.createDraft fails, requiring scope gmail.settings.basic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have a verified Gmail add-on that uses the restricted scope `gmail.settings.basic`. I received a message from Google that it needs to be re-verified.

I found a simpler approach requiring no restricted scopes, and am attempting to update my add-on. I removed `gmail.settings.basic` from my project's oAuth consent screen and from my add-on's `appscript.json`, and deployed my add-on in test mode.

But it fails in the call to `GmailApp.createDraft`:

```
Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: ( 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic || 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || 
https://mail.google.com/)
```

I find no docs saying that `GmailApp.createDraft` requires scope `gmail.settings.basic`, and it doesn't make sense that it would be required.

Is there something else I need to change to let go of the requirement for `gmail.settings.basic`?

Answer (score 0):

I misinterpreted the error message, thinking it said `createDraft` requires *all* listed scopes, not *any* listed scope.

I added `.../auth/gmail.readonly`, which seems at least somewhat related to `createDraft` and is listed as "sensitive" [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes). Apparently the doc is outdated, as `.../auth/gmail.readonly` appears as "restricted" in the oAuth consent screen UI. So I'm stuck with a restricted scope, but now understand why.